# Procesos Background de Oracle - PMON

Tags: oracle

Holaa, me podrían ayudar ?

El proceso PMON está fallando y se necesita revisar sus registros de actividades. ¿Dónde puedo encontrar?

Según lo que leí esta seria más o menos:

/u01/db/admin/xe/_____

Pero el necesario al final no sé cual sería

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Qué tiene que ver Cassandra con la pregunta? Qué versión de Oracle? (presumo xe pero ni idea qué versión)

Comment: Perdón no me había fijado. Es la versión 11g

Comment: Según [esta página](http://www.oracle-wiki.net/premium:startdocslogfiles), debiera estar en `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/database_name/SID/trace/SID_pmon_PID.trc`, donde `SID` es el SID de la base de datos y `PID` es el ID del proceso.

Comment: Graciaaas jachguate me ha sido de graan ayuda